Is it true that even after getting Moksha, a person want to get born again and again just to do bhakti of god?
I had read somewhere, perhaps in a verse of Shrimad Bhagwad Mahapurana, that even after getting Moksha, a person still wants to get born again and again (in Hindu religion) just to do bhakti of god again and again as doing bhakti of god is considered as greater than the bliss of Moksha.
Is it true ?

If after moksha, mind is destroyed. How can soul think? The soul is already God him self. The Soul is merged with Bhraman correct? May be Moksha can have multiple stages I guess. Let’s wait for answers.

Gaudiya Vaishnavites elevate Krishna-bhakti over Moksha - and in fact say that desire for Moksha is an impediment.
https://btg.krishna.com/liberation-from-the-desire-for-liberation/

A further consideration on the relationship between mukti and bhakti is that even though bhakti is clearly the highest goal, mukti can be used in the service of Krishna. For instance, the four types of mukti that Sarvabhauma Bhattacharya listed above can encourage and facilitate our service to the Lord. So what exactly is the culprit here? The answer: not mukti itself, but the desire for it. In Bhakti-rasamrita-sindhu (1.2.22), Srila Rupa Goswami writes,


bhukti-mukti-spriha yavat
pishachi hridi vartate
tavad bhakti-sukhasyatra
katham abhyudayo bhavet


“The material desire to enjoy the material world and the desire to become liberated from material bondage are considered to be two witches, and they haunt one like ghosts. As long as these witches remain within the heart, how can one feel transcendental bliss? As long as these two witches remain in the heart, there is no possibility of enjoying the transcendental bliss of devotional service.”


Pure devotees who live every moment of their lives in pure love for Krishna do not have even the desire to go back to Godhead (living on the same planet as the Lord, salokya), to attain the same bodily features as the Lord (sarupya), to get the direct association of the Lord (samipya), or to get the same opulences as the Lord (sarshti). All they want is to serve the Lord birth after birth, wherever they may be.


Is there any such verse in Bhagwad Purana ? I remember reading such a thing.

This is, I guess, a unique standpoint. All other Hindu sects consider mukti to be the final destination. Gaudiya Vaishnavas are quite strange people.

According to Bimba-pratibimba-vāda(बिम्ब-प्रतिबिम्ब-वादम्/Theory of Reflection), Suddha Māyā(Māyā associated with Sattva Guna) and Asuddha Māyā (Avidyā/अविद्य/Māyā associated with tamo guna) act like reflecting media. When Brahman is reflected in Suddha Māyā, it becomes Īśvara and is known as Saguna brahman(सगुण ब्रह्मन्/Qualified Brahman). Though Īsvara is also a Ĵivātman like us, but unlike us, He is the purest and the most virtuous soul attached with Prakriti with Sattva Guna. So Māya(माया/Prakriti/Illusion) becomes subservient to Īsvara rather than veiling Brahman.
God Īsvara(ईश्वर/ஈஸ்வரன்) gives opportunity and level playing field by creating and sustenance of this universe to each and every Jīvātman(जीवात्मन्) in order to struggle and attain liberation from samsāra (संसार/Cycle of birth and death). Thiruvalluva Muni(तिरुवल्लुव मुनि/திருவள்ளுவர்) in his Thirukkural (तिरुक्कुरल्/திருக்குறள்), a Tamil Spiritual Granta about Purushārtam(पुरुषार्थम्/Four ultimate goals of human life viz. Dharma, Artha, Kāma and Moskha respectively in Hinduism), delineates in 10th sloka(out of 1,330) the following:

பிறவிப் பெருங்கடல் நீந்துவர் நீந்தார் இறைவன் அடிசேரா தார்
Swim Ocean of Cycle of Birth, those who does[swim successfully] will reach the feet of God[Brahman], others [those who do not] will drown.
Keep in mind Brahman(ब्रह्मन्/Supreme Spirit/परमात्मन्/பரம்பொருள்) is infinity, so are His Feet!
Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) is another opportunity for those Who drowned in the Ocean of Samsāra(संसार/Cycle of Rebirth) in order to swim across to attain Moksha(reach Feet of God).
Punarjanma(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) is effected by none other than the Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) and this process (of Punarjanma) repeats for those Who drowned until they swim across successfully to reach the Lotus Feet of God(Brahman)!
Punarjanmas(पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) are innumerable and countless!

Observe that Thiruvalluva Muni never mention about reaching abodes such as Swarga Loga(An abode of Devas/Paradise), Satya loka(An abode of God Brahma and Goddess Saraswati), Vaikunta Loka(An abode of God Mahavishnu and Goddess Mahālakshmi) or Kailāsam(An abode of God Rudra and Goddess Pārvati) for those who swam successfully the Ocean of Samsāra(संसार/Cycle of Existence or Rebirth). He only implies Ĵivātmans [those who swam successfully] identify themselves with Brahman and becomes one!
What is the proof for “Reaching Vaikuntam is not Moksha”? Every one who follows Hinduism knows about Jaya-Vijaya who are the Dwāra-Pālaka(द्वार पालक/Gate Keeper) of Vaikunta who were cursed by Sanakādhi Munis(Sanaka, Sanatana, Sanāndana and Sanat kumara who are mind-born sons of God Brahma) when they were denied entry into Vaikunta. According to the curse, Jaya-Vijaya would be born as Hiranya-Hiranyakasipu(हिरण्य-हिरण्यकशिपु) in Krita Yuga(कृत युगम्), Rāvana-Kumbakarna (रवण-कुम्भकर्ण) in Treta Yuga(त्रेता युगम्) and Dantavakra-Shishupāla (दन्तवक्-शिशुपाल) in Dvapara Yuga(द्वापर युगम्). By reaching Vaikunta is really amounting to liberation then why were Jaya-Vijaya, who reside in abode Vaikunta, cursed to take births, that denies logic of Moksha. Therefore arriving at Vaikunta cannot be considered as Liberation.
What is the proof for “Being in Kailāsam is not Moksha”? Once, when Ālāla Sundarar was living by the side of God Shiva in Kailāsam, serving the God and bringing flowers from the garden for His worship, Sundarar cast a lustful look at Aninditi and Kamalini, the attendants of Goddess Parvathi who had also gone to the garden to collect flowers for the Divine Mother's worship. They, too, fell in love with Sundarar. Lord Siva, through His divine vision, understood all that had happened in the garden. He cursed Ālāla Sundarar by saying, "Sundara, since you fell in love with these girls, you and they, too, will go down to the earth and take a human birth. You will marry them and enjoy the pleasures of the world. Accordingly, Ālāla Sundarar took the human incarnation of Sundara Murthi Nāyanār who is one of 63 Nāyanārs, at the same, both Aninditi and Kamalini took the human incarnation as Sangiliyār and Paravayār respectively. Therefore being in Kailāsam can never be considered as Liberation.
What is Jeevan Muktan(जीवन् मुक्त/Liberation While Alive)? The term Moksha is mistaken to the state accomplished after death i.e. falling of gross body at the end of life-span. Such a notion is absolutely wrong, because state of Moksha will be acquired, while living this present and final birth, is known as Jeevan Mukta. A Yogi, after burning seeds of Samskāras of Sanchita Karma so that there will be no reincarnation again nevertheless the final and present life is due to the Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म/begun/commenced) which Yogi has to experience until the gross body falls at the end of life-span. Will yogi commit karma again? Never, because any karma produced will be called Āgamya Karma(आगम्य कर्म/Having Arrived) which will lead to reincarnation again. Then how does Yogi avoid Āgamya Karma? By dedicating(समर्पण/Samarpanam) results of his every action committed in this life to God Īswara!
Conclusion:
Thiruvalluva Muni implies very clearly that the moment Ĵivātman accomplishes Moksha (identify oneself with Brahman and becomes one), he will never be reborn again.
